# Flexbox works in Internet explorer but does not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flexbox

What I would like to achieve: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL5z6gb7/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">11</div>
    <div class="box">12</div>
    <div class="box">13</div>
</div>
```

What I would like to have is that the 'X' amount of "box" classes fit in and make the "content" class wider when more "box" classes are placed.

In Internet Explorer(11) you see that the "box" class fit in the "content" class and expands it, but in Chrome(41) the "box" classes seem to float above the "content" class and outside the "content" class width. This is annoying because if I wand to place another "content" class next to it, it will overlap the first one.

Can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong? If it is a Chrome glitch any suggestions to accomplish this without flexbox?

**Solved**: [Check other topic for multiple containers!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29222970/3303965)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll suggest you to not mix `float: left;` with `display: flex;`. Consider specifying `display: inline-flex;` instead.

That said, I'm afraid you have to do a little computation, to find the biggest offset right (including margins) of all the children inside the container element :

The following piece of code requires jQuery, and is supposed to run when the DOM is ready :

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Find the biggest offset right among all children, relatively to the container
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var maxOffsetRight = 0,
    currentOffsetRight;

$('#container').children().each(function() {
   currentOffsetRight = $(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth(true);
    if (currentOffsetRight > maxOffsetRight) {
        maxOffsetRight = currentOffsetRight;
    }
});

// Set the width of the container
var offsetLeft = $('#container').position().left;
$('#container').css('width', maxOffsetRight - offsetLeft);
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL5z6gb7/9/)**

Note: You might think of an algorithm that looks for the offset right of the last child. That would work in most cases, but that could fail as well as you can set a property `order` on the flex items, to reorder them. Therefore the last child in the DOM is not necessarily the one that has the biggest right offset. That could also fail without reordering elements, if the children have arbitrary width. For example if the child before the last, in the same column, is larger than the last.

Comment: Thanks, Michael P.
It al seems to work in IE, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, so thanks for the effort!
That is some smart jQuery you made there, it doesn't seem to work on my old android mobile phone browser i need to fiddle with that(not really necessary).
Thanks for the effort, you really helped me!, 807

Comment: Michael P.
I cant get it correctly functioning, could you make a complete .HTML file?

Comment: You can see the complete HTML of the document in an iframe if you inpect the result of the fiddle. Maybe the javascript part you wrote is executed before the elements are in the document. Try putting the javascript part just before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrap the whole js in `$(function(){ ...js here... })`.

Comment: I found the problem: the script jquary version had no http: before the backslashes in the url, maybe jsfiddle edited it out.

can the script be modified that it only detects one '.container'? i have the issue that when i place another '.container' with a other amount of .box classes, the scrips freaks out.

Is it possible i place the script inside the '.container' div from who i wand the '.box' amount info? In the other '.container' div other amounts, a other scrips wish only focuses on that particular div ?
(maybe this is for a complete new topic question, and i ask to much of you)

Comment: Actually there are a lot of new questions here. As this question was already answered, you should replace the accepted mark, and open a new question. That way more people will see the question and could answer.

Comment: I shall create a new topic with these questions, thanks for your effort!

Comment: That will be more convenient to answer than in comment, plus that could benefit to others:)

Comment: @807, I updated the answer to substract the left position offset, in case others are interested by the answer.